# Creating a bat file which executes SQL scripts

Tags: sql, batch-file, automation

I have a folder into which a number of MSQL scripts get dropped into after each weekly sprint. For example, 10 scripts were placed into the folder today. I had to then open each script individually and run it against the applicable database. The database that it needs to be run against is in the name of the file.
e.g. [2] [CRMdata]UpdateProc.sql

The [2] represents the sequence in which it is run, so script [1] needs to be run before it.
[CRMdata] is the database I have to run it against.

This process is very tiresome, especially if there are 50 scripts to run sequentially.
I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this?
Perhpas a .bat file, which reads the filename, and executes the scripts sequentially based on the script number, as well as executing it against the database specified in the file name.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Windows, since you say "batch file". You'll have a less frustrating time if you use a better scripting language, such as VBscript or Javascript via Windows Scripting host, or Powershell. With one of these, it would be more or less trivial to do (read the file names, parse them and build your commands).

Comment: I would definately use VBScript for this one. Use FileSystemObject to get the list of scripts.

Comment: What is `MSQL`? `MS SQL` or `MySQL`?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you need to run things, consider using SQL Server Job Agent.  This is a good way to schedule simple things.

For a task like this, I would recommend PowerShell in combination with "sqlcmd".  This command is actually the answer to your question, since it will run scripts from the command line.

However, go a step further.  Schedule a job that runs once per week (or whenever you want it run).  Have it consist of one step, a PowerShell script.  This can then loop through all the scripts in the directory, extract the file name from the name, and run the script using sqlcmd.  Along the way, also log what you are doing in a table so you can spot errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about executing SQL with MSQL. You will have to work out how to run each script against the proper database using whatever command-line utility is provided for MSQL.

I can help you with a batch file that will sort the SQL files in the correct sequence order, and parse out the name of the database.

The job is much easier in batch if the sequence numbers are zero prefixed to be a constant width. I'm assuming it is OK to rename the files, so that is what this solution does.

I also assumed you will never have more than 999 files to process. The code can easily be modified to handle more.

Some changes will have to be made if any file names contain the `!` character because delayed expansion will corrupt the expansion of the FOR variables. But that is an unlikely problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Change the definition to point to the folder that contains the scripts
set "folder=sqlCodeFolder"

:: The mask will only match the pattern that you indicated in your question
set "mask=[*] [*]*.sql"

:: Rename the .sql files so that the sequence numbers are zero prefixed
:: to width of 3. This enables the default alpha sort of the directory to be
:: in the proper sequence
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%A in ('dir /b "%folder%\%mask%"') do (
  set seq=00%%A
  ren "%folder%\[%%A]%%B" "[!seq:~-3!]%%B"
)

::Process the renamed files in order
for %%F in ("%folder%\%mask%") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=[] " %%D in ("%%~nF") do (
    rem %%F contains the full path to the sql file
    rem %%D contains the name of the database, without enclosing []
    rem Replace the echo line below with the proper command to run your script
    echo run %%F against database [%%D]
  )
)
```